# Cocoa app gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS on any GL function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, exc-bad-access

It seems that no matter what GL function I call, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. However, I'm calling these functions in `readFromURL:ofType:error:` of an `NSDocument` subclass, for some offscreen drawing. If I remove that code, and try to use GL later, once everything's loaded, everything works fine. Is this a GL context issue?

I read Apple's GL guide, but in the section about offscreen drawing, it just told me how to use framebuffers. Which I do, but since `glGenFramebuffersEXT` crashes just like everything else, it's not very helpful.

Is there some sort of context creation I need to perform, and if so, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OpenGL calls need a context. If you have `NSOpenGLView`, you need to get its context and make it current:

```
[[openGLView openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
// glCalls()
```

If you're not using `NSOpenGLView`, you can create `NSOpenGLContext` youself.

Comment: Thanks. Seems annoying to have to manage a bunch of contexts--is there a reason not to have all my custom views use a single context? Also, for those finding this question later, creating your own `NSOpenGLContext` looks like this: `[[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:[NSOpenGLView defaultPixelFormat] shareContext:nil]`.

Comment: You can have your contexts share textures and other objects using that `shareContext:` parameter, so you won't have to create them again for each context.

Comment: I gave that a shot, but it seemed like I would still have to load my shader once per context?